# Python 2.7 TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for %:'None type' and str

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I've got an issue where when i try to print 'filename' i get this error

```
line 101, in purchase_code_fn
    print("QR Code Created: %s") %(filename)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Below is the offending function.

```
def purchase_code_fn():
    count=+1
    name = raw_input("Name: ")
    email_prompt = raw_input("Please enter your email address: ")
    userid = uuid.uuid4()
    filename = (str(email_prompt)+str(count))
    print("QR Code Created: %s") %(filename)
    qr_code_fn(email_prompt, userid)
```

A pointer in the right direction would be fantastic.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you getting proper input into `email_prompt`?

Comment: The error did not come from python 2.7. I updated the tag. Python 2.7 treats `print` as a statement and the code would work. Python 3.* treats `print` as a function and results in this error.

Comment: @viraptor It's from Python 2.7.12 as that's the only version i've installed (:

Comment: @SamuelHarrison I'm guessing you used `from __future__ import print_function` then? It needs to be included in the code to be a proper 2.7 question. Otherwise, it's just the same as 3.x.

Comment: @viraptor Yup, i made sure to put it as the first import as well (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to run Python 2 code with Python 3. In Python 3, `print` is a function, but a *statement* in Python 2.

The `print` function had already been executed and the formatting did not come a priori as you intended or would have in Python 2. So you are trying to format the `None` returned by `print`, which is clearly not going to work.

You should remove the closing parenthesis trailing the string:

```
print("QR Code Created: %s" % filename)
```

Comment: Or, even simpler, let `print` do the heavy lifting instead of formatting a string, then printing it: `print("QR Code Created:", filename)`